# How to check if an action is already fired?

Tags: actions, conditional-tags

How to check if an action is already fired in a function for example:

```
function foo() {
  // checking if the action 'wp' is fired
  if( !action_fired('wp') ) {
    trigger_error('invalid call');
    return;
  }

  if( is_front_page() ) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

I want to check that because:

1. WordPress conditional tags like `is_front_page` won't work being called before the 'wp' hook.
2. Still, these conditional tags can be called before 'wp' without any warning or notices

So writing a function like `foo()`, I want to ensure it is called properly by throwing an error if the 'wp' action hasn't fired at that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to check if an action is already fired?

The [`did_action( $tag)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/did_action/) function returns the number of times the `$tag` action hook has fired.